# Model selection using AIC in Survival Analysis

Tags: r, model, survival

As far as I know, the model with lowest AIC is said to be better. However, according to the R output below, the writer says, the model called `wei` is better, whose AIC is the highest (`-65.25`). What do you guys think?

[image]

Comment: This is not a specific programming question. If you have a question about the interpretation of results from statistical methods, it would be better to ask at [stats.se].

Comment: I agree that this is indeed the worst model, it seems that the author has not seen the minus in front of the scores. In addition, the "wei" model is only 1.7 points worse than the "exp" model, which is also not very strong evidence for it to be the "worst" model.